# How to center align /makecvheader in AltaCV template

Tags: header-footer, align, center

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.6.5, 3 Nov 2022) written by LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com). Compiles with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}
%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and packages.
%% See http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontawesome5 for full list of symbols.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.2cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{Grey}{HTML}{808080}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{Blue}
\colorlet{heading}{Black}
\colorlet{headingrule}{Black}
\colorlet{subheading}{Blue}
\colorlet{accent}{Blue}
\colorlet{emphasis}{Black}
\colorlet{body}{Grey}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}


% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% Use (and optionally edit if necessary) this .tex if you
%% want to use an author-year reference style like APA(6)
%% for your publication list
% \input{pubs-authoryear}

%% Use (and optionally edit if necessary) this .tex if you

\begin{document}
\name{Rahul Khandait}
\tagline{Computer Science Undergraduate Student}
%% You can add multiple photos on the left or right
% \photoR{2.8cm}{Globe_High}
% \photoL{2.5cm}{Yacht_High,Suitcase_High}

\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  \email{rahulkhandait84206@gmail.com}
  \phone{8420629304}
  % \location{Location, COUNTRY}
  % \homepage{www.homepage.com}
  \twitter{@rahulkhandait_}
  \linkedin{rahulkhandait}
  \github{rahulkhandait-sde}
  % \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
  %% You can add your own arbitrary detail with
  %% \printinfo{symbol}{detail}[optional hyperlink prefix]
  % \printinfo{\faPaw}{Hey ho!}[https://example.com/]
  %% Or you can declare your own field with
  %% \NewInfoFiled{fieldname}{symbol}[optional hyperlink prefix] and use it:
  % \NewInfoField{gitlab}{\faGitlab}[https://gitlab.com/]
  % \gitlab{your_id}
  %%
  %% For services and platforms like Mastodon where there isn't a
  %% straightforward relation between the user ID/nickname and the hyperlink,
  %% you can use \printinfo directly e.g.
  % \printinfo{\faMastodon}{@username@instace}[https://instance.url/@username]
  %% But if you absolutely want to create new dedicated info fields for
  %% such platforms, then use \NewInfoField* with a star:
  % \NewInfoField*{mastodon}{\faMastodon}
  %% then you can use \mastodon, with TWO arguments where the 2nd argument is
  %% the full hyperlink.
  % \mastodon{@username@instance}{https://instance.url/@username}
}
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}
%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
% \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

%% Set the left/right column width ratio to 5:5.
\columnratio{0.5}

% Start a 2-column paracol. Both the left and right columns will automatically
% break across pages if things get too long.
\begin{paracol}{2}
\cvsection{Education}

\cvevent{B.Tech in Computer Science \& Engineering }{Your University}{Sept 2023 -- June 2027}{}
CGPA:  9.5/10
{}

\divider

\cvevent{Higher Secondary Education (Class XII)}{Techno India Group Public School}{June 2021 -- March 2023}{}

\divider
\cvevent{Secondary Education (Class X)}{Ramkrishna Vivekananda Mission Vidyabhavan}{January 2011 -- February 2021}{}

\cvsection{Work Experience}

\cvevent{Job Title 1}{Company 1}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Job Title 2}{Company 2}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}


\medskip

\cvsection{Achievements}
\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Fantastic Achievement}{and some details about it}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}

% use ONLY \newpage if you want to force a page break for
% ONLY the current column
\newpage



%% Switch to the right column. This will now automatically move to the second
%% page if the content is too long.
\switchcolumn

\cvsection{Skills}

% \cvtag{C}
% \cvtag{C++}
\cvtag{Python}
\cvtag{MySQL}
\cvtag{HTML}
\cvtag{CSS}
\cvtag{Bootstrap}
\cvtag{JavaScript}



% \divider\smallskip

% \cvtag{Hard-working}
% \cvtag{Eye for detail}\\
% \cvtag{Motivator \& Leader}
\cvsection{Projects}
\cvevent{}{Spotify - Web Player: Music for everyone  \href{https://github.com/rahulkhandait-sde}{\github{}}}{July 2023 - July 2023}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Developed a replica of Spotify, a renowned music streaming platform.
\item  Enabled users to enjoy their favorite music, explore playlists, and discover new tracks.
\item Utilized HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to implement the project.\end{itemize}
\divider

\cvevent{}{Amazon.com. Spend less. Smile more. \href{https://github.com/rahulkhandait-sde}{\github{}}}{June 2023 - July 2023}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Developed a replica of Amazon.com, a renowned e-commerce website.
\item Demonstrated expertise in design, functionality, and interactivity to recreate a complex e-commerce platform.
\item Utilized HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to replicate key features and user experience.\end{itemize}



\cvsection{Position of Responsibility}
\cvevent{}{Society Title | Society, College }{}{}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Organized hackathons \& conducted sessions for 300+ college students on Web Development related topics.
\end{itemize}
\divider
\cvevent{}{Society Title | Society, College }{}{}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Organized hackathons \& conducted sessions for 300+ college students on Web Development related topics.
\end{itemize}
\cvsection{Other Activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Hobbies:}  Chess, Cricket
\end{itemize}

%% Yeah I didn't spend too much time making all the
%% spacing consistent... sorry. Use \smallskip, \medskip,
%% \bigskip, \vspace etc to make adjustments.
\medskip
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide the complete code from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added the complete code

Comment: You should also provide the source of the class file.

Comment: Here is the Project link : https://www.overleaf.com/read/dwvgdqsqgnmc

Comment: In the definition of `\makecvheader`, the writer used `\raggedright` to make the name, tagline and personal information to be flushed left. If you want them to be center aligned, you could modify the definition of `\makecvheader`.@Rahul

Comment: @Stephen, I changed the writer to \raggedcenter, but after recompiling, nothing has changed.

Comment: Where did you find `\raggedcenter`? It's not a standard command.@Rahul

Comment: now I used `\centering` and the problem is resolved. Thanks a lot @Stephen for your help.